# How can I list all mySQL records and provide an update button for each?

Tags: php, mysql, webforms

My first post, how exciting!! I just can't seem to figure this out, I am pulling customer records from a specific table and listing all the content (name, payables, dates, ect) in an html table. I wanted to include an 'update record' button next to each row but I'm not sure the best way to do it. I have experimented with creating a button within the foreach loop that echos the data and naming the buttons after one of the row values to identify it. I am sure there is a better way of doing this!

Here's what I have (I am just getting my feet wet with serious php):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $cell) {

            echo "\n<td>$cell</td>";
    }

    echo '<td><form method="POST" action="userupdate.php">
    <input name="update" type="button" value="Update Record" />
    <input type="hidden" name="'.$row[1].'" /></form></td></tr>';
    echo "\n\n";
 }
```

but now I cant figure out how to call the hidden input name. I am sure that this is about the stupidest way to accomplish this (don't be too hard on me!), but I need some help! Maybe there is a better way of doing this other than the button.

There are at least 200 rows in the table.

Comment: Do you have a working solution for updating just one record?

Comment: Thats what i'm working on. I also considered having a check box and a few update fields next to each column instead of the button.

Comment: make it a hyperlink, `edit.php?id=666`

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `name` attribute to something fixed, like 'row_id'. Then, set the `value` to `$row[1]`... this can then be accessed like any other CGI parameter

Comment: Yes, the hidden input should be more like <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $actual_id ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($row as $cell) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "\n<td>$cell['name']</td>"; //this will be all other details you want to show
    echo "\n<td><a href="update.php?id=<?php print $cell['id']; ?>"</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

in your update.php file

```
<?php

$id = floor($_GET['id']);

if($id > 0)
{
    //do your update query and other stmts
}
```